Initializing WinAPI struct COORD (Windows OS) with Kotlin/Native application?
I need to place the cursor at the beginning of the console window. This requires initialization of the platform.windows.COORD structure. How do I do this?
import kotlinx.cinterop.*
import platform.windows.*
import platform.posix.*

@kotlinx.cinterop.ExperimentalForeignApi
fun main()
{
    platform.windows.Sleep(333u);  // OK

    val h : HANDLE? = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE); // OK

    val aaa = memScoped {

        val z: SHORT = 0

        var coord : kotlinx.cinterop.CValue<platform.windows.COORD> // ??? ERROR: Variable 'coord' must be initialized.

        platform.windows.SetConsoleCursorPosition(h, coord)
    }
}


You can create a CValue<T> using the cValue global function. e.g.
var coord = cValue<COORD> {
    X = 10
    Y = 10
}

For more info, see this guide.

Brilliant!!! I have opened 150 tabs in the browser and have not seen such code. Thank you very much!!!
